# Copy data from AWS S3 bucket to Linux SFTP

Tags: linux, shell-script, data

I am writing bash script to copy data from AWS S3 bucket to Linux SFTP.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect
set CURRENT_DATE [lindex $argv 0]

CURRENT_DATE=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
cd /home/ubuntu/test/mydumper

aws s3 cp s3://<directory_path>"/ mydumper --exclude "*" --include "collegeboard.*" --recursive

expect << 'EOS'
spawn sftp <user_name>@<Ip_address>:/Bobby
expect "Password:"
expect "sftp>"
send "<password>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir $CURRENT_DATE\n"
send "cd $CURRENT_DATE\n"
send "mput collegeboard.*\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "pwd\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
EOS
```

I am facing below error:

```
spawn sftp <user_name>@<Ip_address>:/Bobby
Password Authentication
Password:
Connected to fts.collegeboard.com.
Changing to: /Bobby
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /Bobby
sftp> can't read "CURRENT_DATE": no such variable
    while executing
"send "cd $CURRENT_DATE""
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the scp command which doesn't require you to use expect?

Comment: No. Can you provide how we can use it?

Comment: try `scp collegeboard.* <user_name>@<Ip_address>:/Bobby/${CURRENTDATE}` (you must allow passwordless login), also use either bash or expect, your are mixing syntax from both.

Answer (score 0):

See if defining CURRENT_DATE like this inside expect will work.

```
expect << 'EOS'
spawn sftp <user_name>@<Ip_address>:/Bobby
expect "Password:"
expect "sftp>"
send "<password>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mkdir $::env(CURRENT_DATE)\n"
send "cd $::env(CURRENT_DATE)\n"
```

Comment: Hi Alex,

I had tried this previously but facing below error:


sftp> can't read "(date +"%Y%m%d")": no such variable
    while executing
"echo "Current date1 $(date +"%Y%m%d")\n""